When ValidateValue Callback returns a false value, it always throws an exception
public double ADouble
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ADoubleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ADoubleProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ADoubleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ADouble", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, PropertyChanged, CoerceValue), ValidateValue);

private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Old Value : {args.OldValue}\nNew Value : {args.NewValue}");
}
private static object CoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    var a = (double)value;
    if (a > 100.0)
    {
        return 100.0;
    }
    else if (a < -100.0)
    {
        return -100.0;
    }
    return (double)value;
}
private static bool ValidateValue(object value)
{
    var a = (double)value;
    if (a == 1000.1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ADouble = 1000.1;
}

System.ArgumentException:““1000.1”不是属性“ADouble”的有效值。”
我让ValidateValueCallback直接返回false,结果在InitializeComponent方法执行时就抛出了异常.
ArgumentException: “ADouble”属性的默认值无效，因为 ValidateValueCallback 失败。

First check the [object value is not null or !=null], then wrap it into try..catch to diagnose it and to prevent crashing the application
